# How to take a text file's contents away from another text file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

So i want to take a text file's contents away from another text file but on very large data sets

**file 1:**

```
ligand1
ligand6
ligand9
ligand4
```

**File 2:**

```
ligand1
ligand9
```

**Output File**

```
ligand6
ligand4
```

I've been using this `grep -v -x -f file1.txt file2.txt > new_file.txt`
But on big data sets it crashes

Comment: Using `grep` is the best option there is. Is this GNU `grep` we are talking about?

Comment: If the files are sorted (or can be sorted), it may be more efficient to use `comm` or `join`.

Comment: Have you considering using a database for this.  There are command line options - and querying is what databases are for.

Comment: AA. Defined 'very large data sets' (Petabytes?) . A. Please define 'crash'. If you're getting an error msg, please update your Q with that msg. (Maybe you are running out of diskspace?) .Good luck.

Comment: It isn't possible to sort the files @SvenMarnach

Comment: AA: Gigabytes A: It says 'Killed'  B:Was just a mistake @shellter

Comment: Updated also @shellter

Comment: @user3667111: Can you try out my below solution `awk` and comment on its performance?

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't even see the answer, cheers mate @Inian

Comment: so you're getting `killed` and that is all? `killed` sounds like a manual action by an admin. Could that be possible?   Is this a 3rd party hosted machine or do you work in a highly controled industry? (This isn't linux running on AIX is it?)  Did you confirm that you have room to store working copies of both files? Maybe  you need to find different mount points with extra diskspace on your system? `du -h /` ? What do you get when you use `time grep ...` ? Please update your Q with this info, as this comment thread is getting rather long. Good luck.

Comment: Your answer definitely didn't help me get to my answer @Inian

Comment: I didn't downvote you, and your answer just confused me it didn't help @Inian

Comment: @user3667111  If you can provide constructive feedback over what part is confusing, I can improve it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple `awk` logic for this:-

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{list[$0];next} !($0 in list)' file_2 <(tr -d ' ' <file_1)
ligand6
ligand4
```

Which can then be written to a file in some temporary path say, e.g.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{list[$0];next} !($0 in list)' file_2 <(tr -d ' ' <file_1) > /tmp/newFile
```

The `tr` command on file_1 to strip off the leading white-spaces which mangles the `awk` substitutions

The logic is simple:-

- `FNR` and `NR` which keeps track of the row in each file, so when using more than one file, `NR` keeps alive across files and `FNR` resets after a single file(if 1st input has 5 lines and 2nd input has 10 lines then `NR` would be 1,2,3...15 and `FNR` would be 1...5 then 1...1)
- `NR==FNR` and `next` means, this part of codes work only for file_2 i.e. basically all contents of file_2 are copied in that `awk` array named `list`.
- `!($0 in list)` action is then applied on file_1 which will print only those lines which are not already present in file_2. That's it!

Note:- If the extra leading white-space is unexpected and be removed, the overall command performance could be a bit more faster, as this now strips the space for every line.

Comment: So how would I then remove them values?

Comment: You can write it to a new file using the `>` operator always!

Comment: What is this actually doing ?

Answer (score 0):

If your file lines are in the same order, you can use [`comm` command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/comm.html):

`comm -23 file1 file2` print lines only in `file1`

Comment: They are not in the same order